# Split keyword from javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding

How can I split this JavaScript:

```
 encodeUri(this.value).split("/%..|./").length - 1;
```

to C#? Should I use regex for this? I'm trying the snippet below to c# but error on the "/%..|./". It says that cannot convert from string to char.

```
 HttpUtility.Html.Encode(value).Split(@"/%..|./").Length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload of the method [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#overloads) that takes only one string as an input.

You probably want something like this:

```cs
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value).Split(new [] {"/%..|./"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
// or even:
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value).Split("/%..|./", StringSplitOptions.None);
```